# For which $x \in \Bbb R$ does this series converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1+(-1)^k)e^{ikx}}{k^2}$$

I am stuck trying to figure out for which $x \in \Bbb R$ this series converges.

The ratio test doesn't seem to work. (Or my arithmetic doesn't work)

$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \left|\frac{\frac{(1+(-1)^{k+1})e^{i(k+1)x}}{(k+1)^2}}{\frac{(1+(-1)^k)e^{ikx}}{k^2}}\right|<1$$

$$\iff \lim_{k\to \infty} \left|\frac{(1+(-1)^{k+1})e^{i(k+1)x}}{(k+1)^2} \cdot \frac{k^2}{(1+(-1)^k)e^{ikx}}\right|<1$$

I have no idea how to simplify this further. Any ideas?

Comment: The series is absolutely convergent since $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $\|e^{ikx}\| = 1$.

Comment: How do you know $e^{ixk}$ converges to 1=

Comment: I did not write that $e^{ikx}$ converges to something. I wrote that the absolute value of $e^{ikx}$ is one, no matter of $k$ or $x$.

Comment: "...no matter of $\;x,k\;$ **real** ..."

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ :

Since for $\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ , $\;1+(-1)^k\ge 0\;$ , and since $\;x,k\in\Bbb R\implies |e^{ikx}|=1\;$ , we have:

$$\left|\frac{\left(1+(-1)^k\right)e^{ikx}}{k^2}\right|=\frac{1+(-1)^k}{k^2}\le\frac2{k^2}\;,\;\;\text{and since}\;\;\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}$$

converges, so does  the series

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|\frac{\left(1+(-1)^k\right)e^{ikx}}{k^2}\right|$$

and thus your series converges *absolutely*, as noted in the comments.